# Let $M$ be the set $M = ( \frac{1 + 2n^2}{1 + n^2} \in \mathbb{R} : n \in \mathbb{N_0} ) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Find Inf, Sup, Min, Max

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

Let $M$ be the set

$$M = ( \frac{1 + 2n^2}{1 + n^2} \in \mathbb{R} : n \in \mathbb{N_0} ) \subset \mathbb{R}$$

Determine Infimum, Supremum, Minimum and Maximum of $M$, if those exist

---

Minimum: $n = 0$ gives $1 / 1 = 1$

Maximum: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1/n^2 + 2}{1/ n^2 + 1} = 2/1 = 2$$

But it never really reaches this value, because it tends to it. So there is no maximum.

The Infimum is $1$, and the Supremum is $2$

Is that correct ? We have no solutions to this exercise, please give me your feedback. Thank you !

Comment: I think it is correct, because $M=2-\frac{1}{1+n^2}$.

Comment: @kmitov So it's correct ? The Supremum is never reached, is that true ? Thank you very much for your help ! Feel free to post an answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $\frac{2n^2 + 1}{n^2+1} = \frac{2n^2 + 2 -1}{n^2+1} = 2 - \frac{1}{n^2+1}$.

From this, it is clear that minimum (hence infimum) is at $n=0$ ie. $ \min M = \inf M = 1$

$2$ is an upper bound for $M$ and difference between $2$ and elements of $M$ is of the form $\frac{1}{n^2+1}$, which can be made sufficiently small but never zero. So, $2$ indeed the supremum of $M$ but at the same time it can't be the maximum.